# Is it possible to add script creating realm database from JSON to my project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I want to bundle read-only realm database with my app. I was able to do this by following [this tutorial](https://fluffy.es/preload-database-in-app-using-realm/#preparing). There are couple of issues with this solution though. The fact that I had to create another xcode project for it comes with various cons like:

1. I have to keep duplicates of my classes inheriting from Realm Object and manually keep them in sync between two projects
2. I have to open another project each time I want to create new updated realm database
3. It would be weird to keep 2 xcode projects in one git repository

My question is: Is it possible to add some kind of standalone script to my project that would have access to my realm objects and realm library that I could manually run from time to time instead of having to do that in another project?

I was looking into [adding playground](https://medium.com/@LogMaestro/adding-playgrounds-to-your-xcode-project-79d5ea0c7087) and running it from there, but I think that swift package manager is [currently bugged in a way that doesn't allow to build such a solution](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-13739) as I'm getting `This will result in duplication of library code.` error that cannot be fixed with `DISABLE_DIAMOND_PROBLEM_DIAGNOSTIC` flag.

Is there some other solution than having to do it within another project? I think there must be a way to run utility scripts like this - that aren't strictly part of the app, but surprisingly I couldn't find any so far.

Comment: The question is unclear; why do you have to create another XCode project? Why are you creating duplicates of your classes? It's not really clear what bundling a realm with your project (which will be read only) has to do keeping a new updated realm database. Can you clarify the *question*? Update it and we'll take a look.

Comment: There is no tool for creating a realm database to bundle (containing preset static information that won’t be modified, added or deleted by user). So in order to create such a database I'm opening new project, importing Realm, copying classes that describe Realm objects, parsing JSON to fill instances of those classes, saving them and copying .realm file to original project. It works, but comes with described issues. Basically what I'm asking is: is it possible to setup script (?) that would do that from the original project, but that wouldn't be part of the app itself, and to run manually.

Comment: @Stormwaker You can have two targets in one Xcode project. Besides your app, add another target to populate a realm file. You can also add a build phase script and copy the pre-populated realm file when you build your app.

Comment: You may be overthinking this. All you need to do it create a Realm file and drag into your project. The steps are in the [Getting Started Guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-legacy/docs/swift/latest/index.html#other-realms) in the Bundling a Realm section. If you don't want to write code, import the data into Realm Studio and then File->Save Data->Local Realm and drag it into your project. If you want to bundle a realm, it would need to be part of the project so this *that wouldn't be part of the app itself* is a little confusing as it would have to be part of the app if it's static data.